# How to run PythonTeX?

Tags: compiling, python, pythontex

I have a problem running `pythontex`.

My **MWE** is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\py{2+2}

\end{document}
```

This is the **log file**:

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "pyt"
Startup Folder: D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: pyt.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file pyt.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file pyt.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file pyt.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode "D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pyt.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
("D:/Python TeX/pythontex-master/pythontex_quickstart/pyt.tex"
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrartcl.cls"
Document Class: scrartcl 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (article)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrkbase.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrbase.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrlfile.sty"
Package scrlfile, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\tocbasic.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrsize12pt.clo")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\typearea.sty"
Package typearea, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu")))
("D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pythontex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty"
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgfopts\pgfopts.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x")))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\newfloat.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\currfile\currfile.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook-scrlfile.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.dfu")))))
("D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pyt.aux")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)))
No file pythontex-files-pyt/pyt.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.

Package PythonTeX Warning: Missing autoprint content on input line 8.

[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
("D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pyt.aux") ){C:/Program Fi
les/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}<C:/Program Files/MiKTe
X 2.9/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfbx1200.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
ts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb>
Output written on pyt.pdf (1 page, 5473 bytes).
Transcript written on pyt.log.


Command Line:   bibtex.exe "pyt"
Startup Folder: D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: pyt.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file pyt.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file pyt.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file pyt.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode "D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pyt.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
("D:/Python TeX/pythontex-master/pythontex_quickstart/pyt.tex"
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrartcl.cls"
Document Class: scrartcl 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (article)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrkbase.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrbase.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrlfile.sty"
Package scrlfile, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\tocbasic.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrsize12pt.clo")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\typearea.sty"
Package typearea, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu")))
("D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pythontex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty"
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgfopts\pgfopts.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x")))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\newfloat.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\currfile\currfile.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook-scrlfile.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.dfu")))))
("D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pyt.aux")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)))
No file pythontex-files-pyt/pyt.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.

Package PythonTeX Warning: Missing autoprint content on input line 8.

[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
("D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pyt.aux") ){C:/Program Fi
les/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}<C:/Program Files/MiKTe
X 2.9/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfbx1200.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
ts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb>
Output written on pyt.pdf (1 page, 5473 bytes).
Transcript written on pyt.log.


Command Line:   bibtex.exe "pyt"
Startup Folder: D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: pyt.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file pyt.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file pyt.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file pyt.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode "D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pyt.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
("D:/Python TeX/pythontex-master/pythontex_quickstart/pyt.tex"
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrartcl.cls"
Document Class: scrartcl 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (article)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrkbase.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrbase.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrlfile.sty"
Package scrlfile, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\tocbasic.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\scrsize12pt.clo")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\typearea.sty"
Package typearea, 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu")))
("D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pythontex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty"
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgfopts\pgfopts.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x")))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\newfloat.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\currfile\currfile.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook-scrlfile.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.dfu")))))
("D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pyt.aux")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)))
No file pythontex-files-pyt/pyt.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.

Package PythonTeX Warning: Missing autoprint content on input line 8.

[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
("D:\Python TeX\pythontex-master\pythontex_quickstart\pyt.aux") ){C:/Program Fi
les/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}<C:/Program Files/MiKTe
X 2.9/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfbx1200.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
ts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb>
Output written on pyt.pdf (1 page, 5473 bytes).
Transcript written on pyt.log.


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 1)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 2   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

And I get a **pdf file** like this:

[image: running]

I am compiling my file with `pdflatex` but I don't know how to run `pythontex`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whenever code needs to be executed, you need to run LaTeX, then `pythontex.py`, then LaTeX again. If code doesn't need to be executed, you can just run LaTeX by itself. If you installed `pythontex` using the `pythontex_install.py` script, then a shortcut to `pythontex.py` may already exist. You can check for this by running `pythontex --version` on the command line. If a shortcut exists, then running `pythontex` is as simple as `pythontex <name_of_tex_file>`.

Comment: @G.Poore , i'am sorry, i'm really dont understand "how to compile pythontex.py <name_of_tex_file> ?

Comment: What is wrappers/symlinks for `pythontex.py`? And i found here : http://tex.tech.answers.ninja/post/171258

Comment: Wrappers/symlinks are essentially shortcuts for running `pythontex.py`. Once you have those in place, then you can run `pythontex.py` from the command line (or via a shortcut in your TeX editor). Once those are in place, you can compile a file `file.tex` using the command `pythontex file.tex` on the command line. If you haven't already, you should try running the installation script `pythontex_install.py` ([available on ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex)), which should automatically create a batch file so that you can run `pythontex.py` from the command line.

Comment: @G.Poore , thanks for your answer, i try it and succesfull :)

Comment: @G.Poore Why not make your comment a formal answer. I, at least, would upvote it.

Answer (score 19):

Converting my old comment to an answer for future reference: Whenever code needs to be executed, you need to run LaTeX, then `pythontex.py`, then LaTeX again. If code doesn't need to be executed, you can just run LaTeX by itself. If you installed `pythontex` using the `pythontex_install.py` script or your TeX distribution's package manager, then a shortcut to `pythontex.py` may already exist. You can check for this by running `pythontex --version` on the command line. If a shortcut exists, then running `pythontex` is as simple as `pythontex <name_of_tex_file>`.

Answer (score 7):

G. Poore is correct but he is missing something nevertheless.

When you open `cmd` prompt and type `pythontex [name_of_tex_file]` make sure that you are doing this operation in the directory where the `tex` file is stored.

That is, first begin by typing in the cmd prompt: `cd [directory_where_your_tex_file_is_stored]` then hit `enter`, then type: `pythontex [name_of_tex_file]` otherwise it will give you an error: could not find `[name_of_tex_file]`. After `pythontex` successfully compiles the `tex` file, re-run it in TeXMaker or whatever `tex` editor you used.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and got an answer that you don't have an app associated with it to perform the action. Still using cmd I saw that pythontex is installed on the pc. What should I do?